# How to to restart Docker service if it stuck?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I can't restart docker service. After command system just getting stuck.
docker service status is here:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: deactivating (stop-sigterm)
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 1216 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 9
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─1216 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Aug 25 15:08:21 hq-rproxy02 dockerd[1216]: time="2020-08-25T15:08:21.179342033-07:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=
Aug 25 15:08:21 hq-rproxy02 dockerd[1216]: time="2020-08-25T15:08:21.631714600-07:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
Aug 25 15:08:23 hq-rproxy02 dockerd[1216]: time="2020-08-25T15:08:23.607526073-07:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit"
Aug 25 15:08:23 hq-rproxy02 dockerd[1216]: time="2020-08-25T15:08:23.608984581-07:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Aug 25 15:08:23 hq-rproxy02 dockerd[1216]: time="2020-08-25T15:08:23.609119466-07:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Aug 25 15:08:23 hq-rproxy02 dockerd[1216]: time="2020-08-25T15:08:23.609435097-07:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Aug 25 15:08:32 hq-rproxy02 dockerd[1216]: time="2020-08-25T15:08:32.266035465-07:00" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox f2295d6e0a7aec8569c42470bbccbc5a1
Aug 25 15:08:32 hq-rproxy02 dockerd[1216]: time="2020-08-25T15:08:32.677509372-07:00" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modif
Aug 25 15:08:33 hq-rproxy02 dockerd[1216]: time="2020-08-25T15:08:33.339048947-07:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address
Aug 27 05:12:40 hq-rproxy02 dockerd[1216]: time="2020-08-27T05:12:40.330007214-07:00" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"

● docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-08-25 15:07:44 PDT; 5 days ago
   Listen: /var/run/docker.sock (Stream)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 1113)
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.socket

Aug 25 15:07:44 hq-rproxy02 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
Aug 25 15:07:44 hq-rproxy02 systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
```

What can I check?

Comment: To kill the service: `kill -9 1216`, then start it again

Answer (score 5):

Try with `service docker stop`, wait and then `service docker start`.

After it, you can check that the deamon is working succesfully with `docker ps`

Comment: @Yukpun your problem was fixed? if my answer is correct, please confirm this with the check